# pppoe won't start at boot time after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: boot, networking, 16.04, systemd, pppoe

My box while it was running 14.04LTS would start pppoe connection just fine at boot time. I have the proper provider settings at /etc/ppp/peers/ and everything worked perfectly for many years (coming from 12.04LTS days).

Now with latest 16.04.1LTS and systemd (system was upgraded with do-release-upgrade) I noticed that pppoe would not be brought up at boot time.

I am taking my first steps with systemD but as far as I can tell there is no service for bringing pppoe up, I searched for .service files containing the string "ppp" and only pppd-dns.service showed up (and it has nothing to do with pppoe).

I am about to write a unit file for having "pon isp1" executed at boot time but I am quite sure that is not the best way.

Does anyone know what unit file is supposed to trigger the execution of pppoe at boot time? Any clue as to what is going wrong with my box?

Typing "pon isp1" works just fine when run from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Ancient post, but I just fixed this so in case anyone happens by still running 16.04 and pppoe.

In /etc/network/interfaces, the Ethernet interface supporting the pppoe was the stanza underneath:

```
auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set dev eth2 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
```

I moved "auto eth2" above to ensure it was started before.  For some reason, `/bin/ip link set dev eth2 up` isn't enough to have eth2 up.

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /bin/ip link set dev eth2 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider
```

Answer (score 0):

same issue here, updated from 14.04, where adsl was launched at boot.

no luck setting persistent or any other metod listed in 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

Finaly, I fixed adding :

`ip link set  eth0 up
    pon dsl-provider
    exit 0`

at /etc/rc.local

Notice the difference from the wiki in "dev"
`ip link set dev eth0 up`

that doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good workaround. But there ought to be something wrong with systemD on Ubuntu 16.04, PPPoE should be one of the services managed by SystemD, shouldn't it?